# controlling the animation of fade in and fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following markup.

```
<ul id="ticker">
<li><q> Education, then, beyond all other devices of human origin, is the great equalizer of the conditions of men, the balance-wheel of the social machinery </q><cite>Horace Mann</cite></li>
<li><q> The roots of education are bitter, but the fruit is sweet </q><cite>Aristotle</cite></li>
<li><q> Education is what remains after one has forgotten everything he learned in school </q><cite>Albert Einstein</cite></li>
<li><q> Education is the most powerful weapon which you can use to change the world </q><cite>Nelson Mandela</cite></li>
<li><q> Formal education will make you a living; self-education will make you a fortune </q><cite>Jim Rohn</cite></li>
</ul>
```

And the Following script

```
<script>
function tick()
{
$('#ticker li:first').animate({'opacity':0}, 2000, function () { $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).css('opacity', 1); });
}
setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 8000);
</script>
```

The problem is the text fades out nicely but re-appears with a flash. Any way I can make the fade in also smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something more like this:

```
var $ticker = $('#ticker'); // save the static element
$ticker.children(':not(:first-child)').hide();

function tick(){
    $ticker.children(':first-child').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $(this).appendTo($ticker);
        $ticker.children().first().fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
setInterval(tick, 8000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ffe6q/3/

One item is shown at a time, and the displayed item fades out then the next item fades in.

Comment: I'm sure you've already got some styling in mind, so this was more for my personal enjoyment than anything, but have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ffe6q/5/

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
$(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).css('opacity', 1);
```

Do something like:

```
$(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ffe6q/)

```
function tick() {
    $('#ticker li:first').animate({
        'opacity': 0
    },2000, function() {
        $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 2000);
    });
}
setInterval(function() {
    tick()
}, 8000);​
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier and more concise if you used the jQuery effects `.fadeIn(time_in_ms)` & `.fadeOut(time_in_ms)`. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ & http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/.

example: `$('#ticker li:first').fadeIn(1000);`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var $ticker = $('#ticker'); // save the static element
function tick(){
    $ticker.children().first().fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $(this).appendTo($ticker).fadeIn(500);
    });
}
setInterval(tick, 8000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffe6q/2/) based on susanth reddy's

Comment: Note: not shure if children(':first-child') is actually faster than children().first(), had some tests around some time ago but don't find them atm.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make a slideshow, this is what I came up with.
 The css:

```
ul{position: relative;}
li{position: absolute;}
li:not(:first-child){display: none;}
```

and the js:

```
function tick(){
  $('#ticker > li:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#ticker');
}
setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

var $ticker = $('#ticker');

$ticker.children(':not(:first-child)').hide();

function tick(){

```
$ticker.children(':first-child').fadeOut(1000, function () {

    $(this).appendTo($ticker);

    $ticker.children().first().fadeIn(1000);

});
```

}
setInterval(tick, 8000)